# Place corner stamp in top left corner in Masonry?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry

I had been just including my corner stamp as the first item, but I now have a need to prepend new items on the fly rather than append them.  This causes the corner stamp to be pushed down as items are added.

Does anyone know of a work around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of prepending to parent div you can try `after` on the corner stamp.

```
$('.corner-stamp').after('<div>newElement</div>');
```

If you have cases without corner stamp also.

```
if($('.corner-stamp').length){
  $('.corner-stamp').after('<div>newElement</div>');
  $('#container').masonry( 'reload' );
  } 
else{
  $('#container').prepend('<div>newElement</div>').masonry( 'reload' );
  }
```